# Firefox on macOS: Use native fullscreen on videos

Tags: macos, mac, firefox

Is there a way to make Firefox use Mac's native fullscreen when watching a video (e.g. on Netflix)? The browser does go fullscreen, but it's not on it's own space on macOS.

I'm currently using Firefox 57 and macOS 10.13.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not currently implemented in Firefox (see [Bug 1403085](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1403085)).

There is a about:config option that activates the setting with `full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen` set to `true`.

[image: screenshot of the mentioned about:config setting set to true]

1. Type `about:config` in the URL bar
2. Accept the risk and continue
3. Search for `full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen` and set it to `true` using the dobbelt arrow button.

Answer (score 12):

This is now supported in modern builds of Firefox (appears to be implemented since version 70). However, it is not enabled by default. Go into about:config and set full-screen-api.macos-native-full-screen to true.

Answer (score -2):

Usually video players will have a full screen option you can toggle on/off.

Using your example of Netflix, you'll see this option at bottom right when you hover your mouse over the bottom of the video.

[image]

In the screenshot above, the icon at bottom left (immediately below the time remaining) is the full screen icon. Clicking on this will display the video in full screen.

To use a non-Netflix example, the screenshot below is taken of a YouTube video:

[image]

Likewise, at bottom left there is an icon for viewing the video in Full Screen mode. When you click on this icon, you'll see a prompt appear at top like the one below:

[image]

A similar prompt appears whether it's YouTube, Netflix, etc when playing videos in full screen mode.

Finally, to exit Full Screen mode you can just click the icon in the same location at bottom right (or just press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key).

This behaviour (i.e. icons, prompts, <kbd>esc</kbd> key) is independent of the browser. This will work in Firefox, Safari, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but that wasn't really my question. macOS has a native fullscreen where the application goes into its own 'space'. For example. open a Youtube or Netflix video on both Firefox and Safari, and go fullscreen. The one I want is the Safari (or Chrome) one.

Comment: Strange, when I play a YouTube video in Safari and Firefox as follows: (1) just within the browser window, (2) by clicking on the video's full screen icon, (3) by putting both browsers into macOS's full screen mode, and (4) while the browser was in full screen mode, using the video's full screen icon, the only difference I notice between both browsers is that in Firefox I was presented with the *prompt* (i.e. the 3rd image in my answer) if I click on the video's full screen icon. So, I'm obviously missing something! :( However, I'm glad you got an answer, albeit not the one you wanted.

Comment: @Monomeeth, the important difference I know of is the native fullscreen mode moves a window to a separate desktop/space.